# 二次元配列をソートしたい

Tags: javascript

2番目の数値が小さい順に、名前順でソートしたい。
ファイラーのようにフォルダの後にファイルが並ぶ。

配列の1番目の値が名前です。
二番目の値は0がフォルダ、1がファイルとして付けます。
次のコードを実行すると2番目の値に沿ってソートはされますが、配列の内容によっては名前順にソートされません。

```
var ary = [
    ['あ0', 0],
    ['b', 0],
    ['c.txt', 1],
    ['た', 0],
    ['e', 0],
    ['ぜ.txt', 1],
    ['a', 0],
    ['a.txt', 1],
    ['d', 0],
    ['あ', 0],
    ['c', 0],
    ['b.txt', 1],
];

ary.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (a[1] - b[1]) || (a[0] > b[0]);
});

for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
  console.log('%d: %s', ary[i][1], ary[i][0]);
}
```

次の配列に差し替えるとうまくソートできました。

```
var ary = [
    ['あ0', 0],
    ['b', 0],
    ['c.txt', 1],
    ['た', 0],
    ['e', 0],
    ['ぜ.txt', 1],
    ['a', 0],
    // ['a.txt', 1],
    ['d', 0],
    ['あ', 0],
    ['c', 0],
    ['b.txt', 1],
];
```

アドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)に渡している比較関数が間違っています。

```
function(a, b) {
    return (a[1] - b[1]) || (a[0] > b[0]);
}
```

ですが、２番目の値は減算で整数が返されますが、１番目の値については大小比較でbool値が返されてしまいます。

```
function(a, b) {
    return (a[1] - b[1]) || (a[0] > b[0] ? 1 : a[0] < b[0] ? -1 : 0);
}
```

等、条件に合った整数を返すべきです。